# Copy table in access database in another table with C#

Tags: c#, access-data-project

I have created a C# project using MS Access Database and I want to copy data from one table in to another.Is there a simple way to copy all records from one table to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the columns are in the right order, you can do

```
insert into table2
select * from table1
```

If the order of the columns are different between the two tables, you can do

```
insert into table2 (column1, column2, column3)
select column1, column2, column3 from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this sound?

```
INSERT INTO Table2( Field1, Field2, FieldN )
SELECT Field1, Field2, FieldN
FROM Table1;
```